# weak and strong convergence to find an inequality

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence, hilbert-spaces

Let $F : H → H$ be continuous function on a Hilbert space H such that $<F (x) − F (y), x − y> ≥ 0, ∀x, y ∈ H × H$.

Let $x_n \rightharpoonup x$ with $x_n$ a sequence in H such that $F (x_n ) \to l\in H$ when $n\to \infty$.

Prove that $∀y ∈ H, <l − F (y), x − y> ≥ 0 $.

Here we have $\forall n\in \Bbb n: <F (x_n) − F (y), x_n − y> ≥ 0$ and 
I am not sure if we can just make $n\to \infty$ to find the requested inequality? It does not seem that simple to me.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: This follows directly from the monotonicity, since $\langle F(x_n),x_n\rangle \to \langle l,x\rangle$.

Comment: So we can use use at the same time the strong and weak convergences in this inequality? I am asking because I don't see why $x_n$ converges to $x$? It's not a strong convergence?